# How can I improve drainage in a rainy area lawn with little manual labour?

Tags: lawn, drainage

My back garden is very boggy ground and it is located in the midlands in Ireland, so this is common. I tried planting trees to take the excess water and that seemed to help for nearly a year, but in Ireland we get lots of rain.

Are there any easy solutions to my problem without having to do a lot of work?

[image: Picture one]

[image: Picture Two]

Comment: Adding photos of the area would be helpful... are you on low lying land compared to the surrounding area?

Comment: @Bamboo I will take photos and upload later, thank you for your reply, the are is pretty level to surrounding areas

Comment: Is there anyway you could sketch a plan of your property, doesn't have to be to scale, just write the length of property lines, North/South.  Designate neighbors, fences and off site depressions.  If you could borrow or rent a transit and on your map and find at least 3 elevations at 3 spots on your property.  At each of those elevations write the lengths of  distances to establish that spot such as from the corner of your house to one spot and then for the same spot the distance to the fence line the lines perpendicular to each other.  Use property corners, property lines anything established

Comment: Mark on your map where you remember water forming puddles during a rain.  Level sites are sometimes trickier to drain that sloped sites.  There are lots of options but I need to know what you've got going in much more detail.  Are you familiar with maps and construction plans, how to read them and use them?

Comment: If it's *only* a drainage issue, I've heard that acidifying soil can increase the drainage. I'm not sure how difficult that would be for you.

Comment: @stormy I'm sorry I wouldn't have the knowledge or skill set to do that sort of drawing thanks for your input

Comment: what's the topography like?  Is it all flat or is there a gradient?  And how low is the water table?

Answer (score 7):

There are different reasons why your ground could be so wet, I don't know the situation in Ireland, but here in the Netherlands we can have boggy ground as well.

Different reasons are:

- High percentage of clay, or fine sand
- Hard layer because of not maintaining the soil properly
- Natural hard layer to prevent drainage of water
- Ground water level

It depends on the cause to find the right solution.

If it is clay ground you have that is causing the problem, one easy way to deal with it is to add organic matter to your soil. This will soak up water.

If your soil is not tended for a while, you can dig or plough the soil.

For the third reason, you'll need to make vertical drainage holes that reach the ground water level, and fill these holes with something that will drain well (shells, lava rocks, etc.).

The last reason (ground water level), is not something to easily change, unless you want to build dykes, just as we do in the Netherlands...

So the easiest solution in my opinion is to add organic matter to the soil, in order to soak up much of the water in the soil. For organic matter, think of compost or peat.

Comment: Thank you I will try adding some organic matter today, very helpful answer.

Answer (score 3):

Adding Organic matter is not a permanent solution, I would advice adding some fine material like sand might help air out the ground it worked for me....Also try adding more shrubs to try draw up the extra moisture

Answer (score 2):

There are a few things you could do that would work; one would be a 'dry well' that collects the water to slowly be dispersed into the ground without creating mud out of the surface.  This is pretty easy; dig a big trench in the middle of that lawn 10'X 2', install landscape fabric, fill with rounded cobble or 1 1/2" drain rock.  Cover with landscape fabric and then more cobble. The water has a place to go, collect and still be allowed to filter through to the ground water system.

A little more expensive but not much would be turning this area into a graveled surface, 4" deep, using landscape fabric below the gravel. Rent a sod cutter, take out all of the sod (use that soil, mud and grass for creating plant beds), dig down another 2" use that soil on top of the piles of sod you've made into plant beds, use pt 2X4's secured with stakes where you need a clean edge, lay the landscape fabric down, install the gravel (5/8 or 3/8 minus crushed gravel no larger), use a compactor that you can rent and you'll have a nice new clean and usable outdoor room. [image: gravel and cobble aren't boring]

[image: a dry well to drain a front yard that used to be a mucky mess]

[image: removed entire lawn elk were constantly ruining and put in gravel]

Comment: wow, this is very nice work @stormy, this would be a little bit too much work for somebody with my skill set,

Comment: You are seeing too much then.  You most certainly could fix this area correctly.  Sorry, hate to say this, organic will not absorb moisture and fix this problem.  If you spill something and throw paper towels on it and leave it there has the problem been fixed?  A dry well is the cheapest yet very very effective way to solve your problem.  I've got lots more pictures, almost all projects had drainage issues to fix top priority.  Gravel is great.  Dry wells are great.  Organic matter will only make a stickier soup.  Find out how much gravel is, LS fabric, rental of a sod cutter, compactor costs

Comment: What is that area?  I don't do well with metric, sigh, but it looks like 25 feet by 12 feet?  That is 300 sq. ft.?  Divide by 81.  That gives you cubic yards to order for gravel.  That is 3 and 1/2 yards of gravel for 4" depth.   Easier to have it delivered and then either chuted or dumped then wheel barreled onto the prepared area over landscape fabric, edged with 2X4's or not.  The sod cutter would be a huge labor savor but yeah, there is a bit of labor here.  There is no other way to make an easier solution that I can see.  Forget the compactor?  So worth it including the value of your home

Comment: And I am worried about the siding on your home!  It looks very wet.  Is it in contact with the soil?

Comment: I believe your solution to be a better solution, its just we are renting and cannot justify doing this work, I agree with you totally, and I will pass on your suggestions to my landlord, you are correct on the size of the garden

Comment: This is a bit off track but never say never.  You now have the tools with which to give your land lord a proposal.  In exchange for a few month's rent you could make this happen.  He pays for the materials and deliveries.  Anything that you do not want to do yourself.  Bid the job out and get 3 bids for your presentation.  Give him pictures.  Make it work for you, though.  He'd be a fool not to have help upgrading his property.  Also make sure that he won't raise the rent until the next renter!  Just an idea.  That siding if rotting could cause his property value to decrease.  It also causes..

Comment: ...health problems, big time.  Bid it out to 3 companies, licensed, bonded, referenced.  Have those bids broken down to all the specifications so that you can show the land lord where to save, ha, cheap out, or where his money would be best spent.  Make dang sure that you get your due.  Just an idea I've done quite often in the past.

Comment: I totally agree with you and it is getting worse as the seasons go by, I will take your advice and make this proposal to my landlord, I could start the work come spring, thank you for such a detailed response as always

Comment: If the soil is clay, organic matter can certainly improve your soil, and is a much easier solution (like you ask for). It is not only my personal opinion, but you can find [references](https://www.gardeningknowhow.com/garden-how-to/soil-fertilizers/how-to-improve-clay-soil.htm). Well it is your money and time, so it's your decision. Good luck finding the right solution.

Comment: The one and only way to improve any soil is by the addition of decomposed...organic matter.  Definitely improves drainage through the years, especially if the soil is double dug but if there is water sitting around that has absolutely no where to go, no organic matter will help.  It is a physical thing.  That water has to go somewhere where it doesn't build up to the point is drowns the topsoil layer.  Decomposed organic matter is the only way to improve sandy, loam, alkaline, clay and even caliche clay (sp)...all soils.  Raised beds with trenches to direct water away...sorry, honestly.

Comment: @stormy, no need to say sorry. In my answer I give many reasons and solutions, also proper drainage such as vertical drainage holes, but since OP asks for a manual less intensive solution, I would suggest the easiest solution first, which is improving the soil it self. No guarantees, I am not a fortune teller. It is not clear which reason (of the four I name) is causing the problem. If it is high ground water levels, OP might invest in your plan, but it would not help either, if you understand what I am trying to say.

Comment: Fluffing up the soil and then adding decomposed organic matter to the surface, couple of inches will in one year be mixed into the soil a good 6 to 8 inches.  Just by the micro and macro organisms coming up to the top eating this stuff (can't eat non decomposed organic matter) then going back into the soil pooping out the digested decomposed organic matter...is the best way to improve any soil!  I am a nut about that fact!  But his soil is saturated, no amount of organic matter will reduce the water.  Drainage is everything.  A place for the water to go other than waiting for it to evaporate.

Comment: I did this for a living, day in and day out...I had to bid and execute and perform.  I taught grading and drainage without the use of computers!  I am the laziest gardener in the world and I don't care how rich a client was, I couldn't stand to spend money needlessly.  I spent most of my time designing, installing and maintaining landscapes in the wettest part of the world with heavy clay soils.  No fortune telling allowed, grins!

Comment: Of course you don't want water to only evaporate, I totally agree with that. But as you see in my first two reasons, it might be that the soil is not in good shape because of neglect. Then maintaining the soil each year (including adding organic matter) would be good enough to make the top layer more permeable for good drainage. But it is not clear what is the cause, that's why I give more possible options.

Comment: All soils are great soils.  Humans just need to learn what soil they have and how to manage it properly.  Problems begin with the building of the home.  The grading and drainage is sadly over looked.  Then home owners get blamed for what the contractors created.  And they believe that it is their problem.  In the states I've worked those states had up to 12 years for discovery and fixing the problem the contractor was responsible for.  The sooner home owners understand that they have the law on their side, the better.  Shabby contractors need feedback and owners need to know who they can hire.